# All text in a cell before the " - " or " : "

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is the Query function capable of taking the contents of a cell and returning everything before the first instance of `-` or `:`?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Obviously, this isn't my actual data, just an example of how the data is written.

Comment: thats not rly a job for `QUERY`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(SPLIT(A:A, ":"), "-")), , 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I do already have a function that does what I'm looking for without Query.  However, the reason I was hoping to do it with query was so that it would be much less complicated, which this absolutely does.  So you pretty much got to the point of my question either way.  Nice!